# .net MVC posting nested model to controller, data set is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, post, model

```
<form method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="ClientList[0].ItemList[0].ItemID">
    <input type="text" name="ClientList[0].ItemList[0].Qty">

    <input type="text" name="ClientList[0].ItemList[1].ItemID">
    <input type="text" name="ClientList[0].ItemList[1].Qty">


    <input type="text" name="ClientList[1].ItemList[0].ItemID">
    <input type="text" name="ClientList[1].ItemList[0].Qty">

    <input type="text" name="ClientList[1].ItemList[1].ItemID">
    <input type="text" name="ClientList[1].ItemList[1].Qty">

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sale(List<ClientList> ClientList)
{
    return View();
}


public class ClientList
{
    public List<ItemList> ItemList = new List<ItemList>();
}

public class ItemList
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
}
```

This is result
[image]

the second loop, items details are not submitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ItemList` is a field, not a property, and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** its value.

Change it to

```
public class ClientList
{
    public List<ItemList> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

As a side note, the `name` attributes can be just

```
<input type="text" name="[0].ItemList[0].ItemID">
```

which allows you to name the parameter in the POST method to anything you want (except `ItemList`)

Answer (score 0):

I used a bit different approach, with named list

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sale(List<ClientList> ClientList)
{
    return View();
}
```